# В/на Украине. В конкретной фразе

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

«В конце октября ряд хакерских атак Bad Rabbit был совершён на компании в России, Германии, Турции и на Украине.»

Без предлога *в* — с предлогом *на* —  фраза выглядит странно. Как можно отредактировать или такое решение единственно верное?

Comment: Только "на" Украине. А лучше — Украйне.

Comment: Это тема обсуждалась неоднократно: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40285/%d0%92-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5, https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46568/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83, https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27794/%d0%a1-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0

Answer (score 1):

Если беспокоит перспектива критики за предлог "в", можно оставить только один, объединяющий - тогда на него никто не обратит внимания (не будет явного сочетания "в Украине"). При желании можно перефразировать и на абсолютно безупречное "в таких странах, как...". На мой личный взгляд, дифференциация предлогов в/на при "Украине" была бы полезна - в зависимости от того, что имеется в виду (территория или государство), - это информативно и потому не требует приведения сопутствующих видовых категорий. Само по себе употребление предлога "на" по отношению к территориям (Полтавщина, Брянщина, т. е. Полтавская или Брянская область...) в русском языке считается украинизмом ("на Украине" встречается и в старых текстах на украинском языке); об этом можно даже у Розенталя прочитать:

> Сочетание на Украину/Украине возникло *под влиянием украинского языка*
>   (ср.: на Полтавщину/Полтавщине, на Черниговщину/ Черниговщине)...

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm